# wix c++ redistributable merge module not working

Tags: c++, wix, installation, redistributable

I'm trying to install the C++ 2013 redistributable using a merge module in Wix. When I build the project, I can see that the msi for the setup project jumps in size to include the .msm file.

When I run the installer though, it doesn't look like the redistributable is installed. I'm new to wix (started today), so i'm hoping that someone can point out what i'm doing incorrectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.1" Manufacturer="NewbieSystems" UpgradeCode="17EE36D8-8D77-47C0-800A-6DF02D0BC9B1">
    <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id='MyInstall' Name='My Install'>
              <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My Install Test" />
          </Directory>
  </Directory>
    </Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Merge Id="MSVCRedist" SourceFile="Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm" Language="1033" DiskId="1" />
</DirectoryRef>

<Feature Id="VCRedist" Title="Visual C++ 2013 Runtime" 
         AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
  <MergeRef Id="MSVCRedist"/>
</Feature>
</Fragment>


<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
<Component Guid="{5C420731-6650-4109-9DD9-C3CF4038F163}">
  <File Source="$(var.MyInstallTest.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: You may need to explain what you're expecting to see on the system after the install. At the risk of stating the obvious, you won't see that mere module - you'll see the VC++ Dlls installed in the appropriate location, anf that location will depend on what version of VC++ you have. It might me WinSxS, maybe System32.

Comment: Hi Phil.

Thanks for the response. It appears that you were indeed not stating the obvious... well at least it was not obvious to me.

I was under the assumption that the installer would install the runtime in the same way that it would if I installed the redistributable manually, and that I would see it in add/remove programs. It appears that was a faulty assumption. When I ran my application, my component worked just fine, even though the redistributable is not in add / remove programs.

I didn't realize that merge modules work like this.

Thanks for the validation of what I was seeing.